# Ejecutar función php en el onclick de un boton

Tags: javascript, php, html, php7

Necesito ejecutar un código php al accionar un botón el código realiza una consulta y devuelve un archivo si lo encuentra

```
if (file_exists($file_example)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file_example));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_example));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_example);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo 'Archivo no disponible.';
}
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas980, bienvenido, así como está formulada tu pregunta, no se entiende, recibes algún error al ejecutar vel código?, no hace lo que esperas?, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: ¿y la pregunta es?

Comment: No te sirve un simple enlace??? `<a href=”miPhp.php?file_example=<?=$file_example;?>” > descargar </a>` y luego coger el get de los datos limpiando para que no te inyecten código malicioso?